# Reducing a MapInfo region to within a radius

Tags: mapinfo

I'm trying to get rid of parts of a region outside of a 20km radius. At this point I have a region A and a circular region C that are centered at the same point.

I tried using overlap(A.obj, C.obj) and it kept crashing, so I tried using check regions to check for overlaps, but it returns the statement:

> "Check Region did not find any data problems"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select and set the larger region as the 'target' (Objects > Set Target). Select the circular region and do Objects > Erase outside.